# Pyspark programing

Tags: windows, pyspark

I run pyspark code on a dataset in Google Colab and got correct output but when I run the code on the same dataset on Google Cloud platform , the dataset changes .

Below is the code I run on Google Colab on the dataset

data = spark.read.text("/content/SmallTrainingData.txt")

#Split the input text into tokens
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="text",outputCol="words")

data = tokenizer.transform(data)

But on Google cloud I get error that Column “text” doesn’t exist : available is Value .

Which suggest that the dataset has changed under Google Cloud environment

Tried checking the environment

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.